# how test a command locally in capistrano

Tags: ruby, testing, capistrano

I need to test some commands locally with capistrano,
whats the best way to test if a command exists locally?

execute, test or capture?

for eg, test if brew is installed locally.

Answer (score 2):

You could test all capistrano command [local](https://github.com/komazarari/capistrano-locally) lucky.

**1:** Install Gem `capistrano-locally`

**2:** In  `config/deploy/staging_and_local.rb`

```
server 'localhost', roles: w%{app web} # no need to set SSH configs.
```

**3:** In `Capfile`

```
require 'capistrano/locally' require the capistrano-locally file
```

World would be happy again !!!